# How to NOT send an assured message via solace JMS

Tags: scala, jms, solace

I have a very simple producer type program that tries to send a ByteMessage to a topic.

My program is receiving the error `com.solacesystems.jms.ConfigurationException: Error sending message - operation not supported on router (Cannot send assured message: Assured message delivery is not enabled on this channel.)`

How do I go about ensuring that the message sent is not an assured message? Is this some solace configuration variable? Here is the simple JMS related code Im trying to use where `bytes` is the object I'm trying to send:

```
val connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val publishDestination = session.createTopic(solace.TOPIC)
val message = new SolBytesMessage()
message.writeBytes(bytes)
val producer = session.createProducer(publishDestination)
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
log.info("Sending message")
producer.send(publishDestination, message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that `Direct Transport` is checked in the connection factory settings on the appliance.

[image: JMS Connection Factory setting page in SolAdmin's]

The `Direct Transport` setting in the connection factory controls the transport to use for non-persistent messages.

Comment: Is there a way to send the message without direct transport enabled?

Comment: This didnt 100% solve my answer but changing my settings via the solace client was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this question by searching on this error message - if you DO want to send a guaranteed message in this case, leave Direct Transport enabled and edit the client profile on the Solace broker to have "Send Guaranteed Messages" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed enforcing QOS:

```
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(topic);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
```